# Will deleting a structure's pointer also delete pointers within the structure?

Tags: c++, struct, destructor, delete-operator

Assume I have a structure with two pointers each pointing to an object that has an implemented destructor. Also assume that the head points to a Listnode structure that has a non-NULL value *student and *next:

```
struct Listnode {    
  Student *student;
  Listnode *next;
};
Listnode *head =  new Listnode;
```

If I use the `delete` reserve word on the Listnode pointer 'head' will it call the destructors within that structures Student class and Listnode class which 'student' and 'next' point-to respectively. In other words, will deleting *head also delete *student and *next provided head was the only pointer to that Listnode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not unless your destructor `~Listnode` calls `delete` on the pointers. Calling `delete` will, however, invoke the destructors of non-pointer members.

Comment: So you can implement a destructor for a structure?

Comment: @PatMurray Absolutely! Whatever you can do in a class, you can do in a `struct` too. In fact, the only difference is that members of the class before the first access declaration (public, private, or protected) are considered private, while the same members of a struct are considered public.

Comment: Structs can inherit like classes, and the default inheritance access is public for struct and private for classes. Another difference, but along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

No!you should delete them manually first, but you could also add the delete codes in the destructor method.